# javascript object array sum values based on two criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, criteria

Hi I have just started in javascript. I have been trying to sum my object array by ZOPR_TNLO and add it to a new array.

so i get a new array with ZOPR_TNLO:, Actions, Values. Please help :)

```
 var acountsJson = [{A0CALMONTH_T: "JAN 2015", ZOPR_TNLO:       "OP.BUBBLES", Actions: "Arrests", Values: "1"},
{A0CALMONTH_T: "JAN 2015", ZOPR_TNLO: "OP.BUBBLES", Actions:  "DrinkDriving", Values: "2"},
{A0CALMONTH_T: "JAN 2015", ZOPR_TNLO: "OP.BUBBLES", Actions:  "DrinkDriving", Values: "2"},
{A0CALMONTH_T: "DEC 2017", ZOPR_TNLO: "DECEMBER 2017", Actions: "Arrests", Values: "3"},
{A0CALMONTH_T: "DEC 2017", ZOPR_TNLO: "DECEMBER 2017", Actions: "DrinkDriving", Values: "0"},
{A0CALMONTH_T: "DEC 2017", ZOPR_TNLO: "DECEMBER 2017", Actions: "Arrests", Values: "5"},
{A0CALMONTH_T: "DEC 2017", ZOPR_TNLO: "DECEMBER 2017", Actions: "DrinkDriving", Values: "0"}
];

var task = ["DECEMBER 2017", "OP.BUBBLES"];

var kpi = ["Arrests", "DrinkDriving"]


var resultsArray = [];
var resultsArray1 = [];

var summedValues1 = 0;

for (var p = 0; p < task.length; p++) { //takes the first task from list of task
for (var e = 0; e < kpi.length; e++) { //takes the kpi from the list

for (var i = 0; i < acountsJson.length; i++) {

if(acountsJson[i].ZOPR_TNLO === task[p] && acountsJson[i].Actions   === kpi[e]){

//console.log(e);
summedValues1 += Number(acountsJson[i].Values);
var task1 = acountsJson[i].ZOPR_TNLO;
var Actions1 = acountsJson[i].Actions;
}

 }//thrid loop which loops through the json data 
 var index = acountsJson.findIndex(x => x.ZOPR_TNLO==task1 && 
 x.Actions==Actions1)
// here you can check specific property for an object whether it exist in 
your array or not
/// Trying to add this to check before push
if (index === -1){
resultsArray1.push({
ZOPR_TNLO: task1,
Actions: Actions1,
SUMMED_VALUES: summedValues1
 })


console.log("no");
 }
 else 

console.log("object already exists");
summedValues1 = 0;
 } //second for loop

}//first loop
```

https://playcode.io/132805?tabs=console&script.js&output

Getting the error "uncaught syntax error unexpected token" for my indexof statement.

I could be going about it completely wrong. All i am trying to do is sum my acountsJson by two keys ZOPR_TNLO *and* Actions (summed value in Values).

Create a new object array that has unique values by the keys e.g.

```
    ZOPR_TNLO       Actions     Values(summed)
  OP.BUBBLES        DrinkDriving        4
  OP.BUBBLES        Arrests            1
  December 2017     Arrests            8
  December 2017     DrinkDriving        0
```

Comment: Can you share the exact result object you look for?

Comment: please add the error, you get. actually it returns something, but does not throw an error. If you like to get another data structure as result, please add this to the question and add a question.

Comment: That `findIndex` statement should probably be `var index = acountsJson.findIndex(x => x.ZOPR_TNLO == task1 && x.Actions == Actions1)`

Comment: Wow thanks slider that was amazing, it fixed the errors and now it is working as expected. Just for my information what i am trying to achieve here, is there a better way to write the code other than the loops?

Comment: Sorry how do i mark the post as completed or answered?

Comment: @karan you can answer your own question or slider can move their comment to an answer so the next person knows how this was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You could take [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) with later [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) for collecting the wanted data and generating the wanted result set.

```js
var data = [{ A0CALMONTH_T: "JAN 2015", ZOPR_TNLO: "OP.BUBBLES", Actions: "Arrests", Values: "1" }, { A0CALMONTH_T: "JAN 2015", ZOPR_TNLO: "OP.BUBBLES", Actions: "DrinkDriving", Values: "2" }, { A0CALMONTH_T: "JAN 2015", ZOPR_TNLO: "OP.BUBBLES", Actions: "DrinkDriving", Values: "2" }, { A0CALMONTH_T: "DEC 2017", ZOPR_TNLO: "DECEMBER 2017", Actions: "Arrests", Values: "3" }, { A0CALMONTH_T: "DEC 2017", ZOPR_TNLO: "DECEMBER 2017", Actions: "DrinkDriving", Values: "0" }, { A0CALMONTH_T: "DEC 2017", ZOPR_TNLO: "DECEMBER 2017", Actions: "Arrests", Values: "5" }, { A0CALMONTH_T: "DEC 2017", ZOPR_TNLO: "DECEMBER 2017", Actions: "DrinkDriving", Values: "0" }],
    task = ["DECEMBER 2017", "OP.BUBBLES"], // ZOPR_TNLO
    kpi = ["Arrests", "DrinkDriving"],      // Actions
    result = Array.from(
        data.reduce((m, { ZOPR_TNLO, Actions, Values }) =>
            (key => task.includes(ZOPR_TNLO) && kpi.includes(Actions)
                ? m.set(key, (m.get(key) || 0) + +Values)
                : m)([ZOPR_TNLO, Actions].join('|')),
            new Map()
        ),
        ([k, Values]) => (([ZOPR_TNLO, Actions]) => ({ ZOPR_TNLO, Actions, Values }))(k.split('|'))
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative, i was trying to use map and reduce but wasnt able to understand them enough to figure it out.